# WSResponse response.allHeaders play.forkrun.protocol.Serializers$playExceptionPickler$.unpickle(Serializers.scala

Tags: scala, response

This is my code :

```
class MainActor(out: ActorRef) extends Actor {
     var headers: Map[String, Seq[String]]
        def getCoursesForUser(userId: Int) {
        val apiURL = "/api/abc1/users/"
        val complexRequest: WSRequest = buildWSRequest(apiBaseURL + apiURL, sslClient)
        complexRequest.get().map {
          implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
          response =>
            headers = response.allHeaders
        }
          pagination(headers)
      }
       def pagination(allheaders: Map[String, Seq[String]]): String = {
       return "1"
       }
      }
```

**Error**

> play.forkrun.protocol.Serializers$playExceptionPickler$$anon$1:
>   Compilation error[class MainActor needs to WSResponse be abstract,
>   since variable headers is not defined

**Goal**

I wanted to pass headers to pagination function (recursively),
How to declare  `var headers: Map[String, Seq[String]]` so that i can pass headers to `pagination()` method which is outside of scope

Comment: how to declare variable which is of type Map[String, Seq[String]] ?

Comment: Use this   ,                    var headers: Map[String, Seq[String]] = Map()